# Create bash script with osascript and passed var

Tags: macos, bash, osascript

I haven't really done much in the way of bash scripts before so any help would be appreciated!

I've added this function to my .bash_profile:

```
function test()
{
    osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to display dialog "$1"'
    echo "my name is $1"
}
```

The second line works fine, however, the first line will just show $1 in the dialog. I have tried a few variations to that line as well as:

```
osascript <<EOD
  tell app "System Events" to display dialog "$1"
EOD
```

Is there a certain way I need to concatenate `$1` on the osascript line, or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to expand the variable `$1`, it must be within double quotes. The outer quotes are single, which is preventing the expansion. Try this:

```
test() {
    osascript -e "tell app \"System Events\" to display dialog \"$1\""
    echo "my name is $1"
}
```

The inner double quotes are escaped, which means they will be passed correctly.

I have also removed the `function` keyword as it serves no useful purpose (except to make your script incompatible with other shells).

Comment: Thanks, Tom! I don't know why I didn't think of just escaping them, but either way it works like a treat. Also, cheers for the heads up on the `function` keyword :)